# pass form entries to another form in different page javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to pass the value entered by a user in a form field from called fare to a different page has a different form called fare1 in javascript

form1:

```
<form action="/estimate-fare" name="fare" method="link" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
  <div class="pickupaddressWrapper">
    <label for="pickupaddress">Pickup Address: <span class="form-required" title="This  field is required.">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="pickupaddress" id="pickupaddress" size="30"  value="" class="form-text required" />
  </div>

  <div class="dropoffaddressWrapper">
    <label for="dropoffaddress">Dropoff Address: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="dropoffaddress" id="dropoffaddress" size="30" value="" class="form-text required" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit"  id="edit-submit" value="" class="form-submit" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around, it hit me... Why not pass the values through another form? No query strings involved, and everything passed right along in the $_POST data.

```
/estimate-fare/index.php

<?php 
$pickupat = $_POST['pickupaddress'];
$dropoffat = $_POST['dropoffaddress'];
$distance = calcDistance($pickupat,$dropoffat); // the function that calculates or looks up distance between points - (float) miles
$time = calcTime($pickupat,$dropoffat); // function to calculate time taken at present time of day - (int) minutes
$fare1 = $distance * 10 * $distancerate; // meter rate per 10th of a mile
$fare2 = $time * $timerate; // meter rate per minute
$estfare = ($fare1 > $fare2) ? $fare1 : $fare2;
?>
<html>
<body>
 ...
 <form method="post" action="summary.php">
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $pickupat; ?>">
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $dropoffat; ?>">
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $distance; ?> Miles">
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $time; ?> Minutes">
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $estfare; ?>">
 <input type="submit" value="Next">
 </form>
 ...
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this will helps alot.

Comment: The name of each input is left out for brevity. Don't forget to add it or your form handler at 'summary.php' won't have anything to work with. And... Don't forget to sanitize. Everything.

Answer (score 0):

If your fare form handler is referring the fare1 page, then one could just pass the value(s) through a query string and suss them out in fare1.